# MVC SessionStateAttribute not working as Global Attribute

Tags: session, asp.net-mvc-3, attributes, session-state

How do you setup SessionStateAttribute as a global filter in MVC3?
In my Global.asax I have this in the RegisterGlobalFilters method.

```
filters.Add(new SessionStateAttribute(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled));
```

And in my home controller I have this.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

        Session["Blend"] = "Will it blend?";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

But for some reason it still lets me use the Session. However if I decorate the HomeController class itself with the attribute, I get an error on the line utilizing the Session about a Object reference being null, which I'm guessing is intended if the Session is never created?

I am starting to wonder if there is something wrong with my project. I've been getting little problems like this one with standard behavior that are *supposed* to just work.

Anyone else had problems with things like this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`SessionStateAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.sessionstateattribute.aspx) is not an [action filter](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/understanding-action-filters-cs), so you cannot add it as a global action filter. It's a special attribute which allows you to decorate your controllers with and have a more fine grained control over the session mode per controller.

To disable the session globally for the entire application put the following in your web.config:

```
<sessionState mode="Off" />
```

Comment: Wow, that's kind of funny. You'd be surprised how many sites I've come across that use the SessionStateAttribute as an example of how to use Global Filters in MVC, I guess none of them actually _tested_ their examples before posting them to the internet :-P