# Global switch to make all controllers sessionless

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, controller, global-asax

Instead of having to go through all the controller classes and apply the proper attribute is there some way to do it globally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a base controller with the proper attribute and have all your controllers inherit from it.

You can also disable session state for entire application, see [Darin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5490001):

> To disable the session globally for the entire application put the
>   following in your web.config:
>   `<sessionState mode="Off" />`

Comment: Well, I should have thought about this! I just was pessimistic about the inheritability of the attribute. MSDN, however, states ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.sessionstateattribute(v=vs.98).aspx ) that it is inherited.